# How to keep data between various pages/controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I set a session variable when requesting the login page by

```
with->('data', $data);
```

and use

```
Session::reflash();
```

in login view to extend the life of this session variable to next request.

In the login page I have a link to another page which only admin user can see it, so I write a filter for that page that need the session variable data.

But when I click the link to make a new request, the data variable already gone. so the filter can not get it.

how can I get the same session variable when I make a new request to other pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the following for you:

```
Session::put("data", $data);
```

Before this line:

```
with->('data', $data);
```

And the in the next request you do:

```
Session::get("data");
```

And when your usage is finished, then you remove it:

```
Session::forgot("data");
```

But if your data are fixed, and should be reused at several places, it is best to provide a service for it, through Models (maybe returning some values via a method).

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent
{
   function SomeData ()
   {
      return array("something" => "sometingElse");
    }
}
```

And in your controller you do:

```
MyModel::SomeData();
```

However you can get data from database also. But if your data are not really database-driven, for instance they are some titles for pages, you can pass it through a BaseController global variable too:

Note that your controllers usually are an extent of another BaseController:

```
class Pages extends BaseController
{

}
```

In your `BaseController` you may define some default values:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
   protected $myValues;

   function getDefaultValues()
   {
      $this->myValues = array("something"=>"somethingElse");
      return $this->myValues; // however this is an example, you may not need any method
      // and the property itself might be enough.
   } 
}
```

Comment: It means provide a central engine/store/provide where you get data from. With model you can distribute data across all of your controllers. Specially in Laravel, with its powerful Model Engine. See my updated answer (you can accept the answer also)